# "Copy but keep both files" but only for files with different timestamps

Tags: windows, ntfs, robocopy, xcopy

I'm trying to consolidate 5 very similar but slightly different tree structures into a single one but not lose any modified data.

So, I need a solution that will:
1. Copy files that exist in the source but do not exist in the destination
2. Skip files that do not exist in the source but do in the destination
3. Skip (ideally) or overwrite files that exist in both the source and destination and have the same timestamp
4. Create copies of files that exist in both the source and destination but have different timestamps

How can I do this? As far as I can see, this can't be done with Xcopy, Robocopy, FreeFileSync, Synchronicity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch renaming utility, such as [this one](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php), could help you do this a number of different ways.

One such method would be to add the timestamps to the names of the files in both folders. Once renamed, you can just move them over and allow Windows to overwrite the duplicates.

Comment: I prefer [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer), myself. :)

Anyway, that would be quite ugly so how would I revert all filenames back to the originals (except for the copies, of course)?

Comment: Bulk Rename Utility allows you to import and export file names to and from .txt and .csv files.

Comment: Yes but renaming the files back to what they were would cause a filename conflict?

Comment: I've added all files to ReNamer, run a rule to add a ":File_DateModified:" suffix to all filenames, merged tree structures overwriting conflicting files, and run a rule to delete from position 1 to position 20 from right (which removes the timestamps). ReNamer's "Fix conflicting new names on preview" option just adds a "(x)" suffix to conflicting filenames like Windows does.

Comment: @mythofechelon Very nice. Is ReNamer freeware? Can you share the link?

Comment: 5.70 was, which is what I have. 5.75 (current) has a Lite version but it is restricted to 5 presets (profiles) and 5 rules but that should be sufficient for most things. http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer

Comment: By the way, I found that some files had different timestamps but the same content so, in future, it would be best to suffix hashes instead.